# Finding a Field in Which a Function Splits into Linear Factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $f(x)=2x^3 +5x^2 +7x+6∈Q[x]$. Find a field, smaller than the
complex numbers, in which f(x) splits into linear factors.

I know that I should use the theorem that says that "If f(x) is any polynomial over the field F, there is an extension field K of F over which f(x) splits into linear factors". What I am unsure on is how I am supposed to find the field K. And further, how I'm supposed to find the linear factors f(x) breaks down to.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The simplest process seems to be to begin by finding the roots $r_1,r_2,r_3$ of $f$. Provided all three are irrational, then an extension would be simply $\Bbb Q(r_1,r_2,r_3)$. If one of them were rational, just ignore it in the extension. (I **think** anyhow. I'm somewhat new to this sort of stuff and this wouldn't be the first time I answered one of these questions thinking I'm correct only to be dead wrong. So grain of salt.)

Comment: Note:  $f(x)=(2x+3)(x^2+x+2)=(2x+3)(x+\frac12+\frac{\sqrt7i}2)(x+\frac12-\frac{\sqrt7i}2)$

Comment: By fundamental theorem of algebra you know that $f$ has three roots in $\mathbb{C}$, say $a_1, a_2, a_3$.  How does $f$ factor in $\mathbb{Q}(a_1,a_2, a_3)$?

Comment: I'm not sure, @mattstokes

Comment: Well, for example, $x^2 - 2$ doesn't factor in $\mathbb{Q}$.  But it does factor as $(x- \sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ (notice that this is because $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$).

Comment: Based on my above comment, I'd suggest adjoining a root of $x^2+7$ to $\mathbb Q$

Comment: Why are you using those polynomials, @J.W.Tanner?

Comment: I factored $f(x)$ in $\mathbb C[x],$ paving the way for @mattstokes' answer (below)

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \mathbb{C}$ be the roots of $f$.  Then, in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ we have that $f(x) = (x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)$.  Since you are looking for a field that is smaller than $\mathbb{C}$, just take $K = \mathbb{Q}(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ (this is called the splitting field of $f$).  Then since $a_1,a_2,a_3 \in K$, we have that $x-a_i \in K[x]$ for $i = 1,2,3$.

In fact, as J.W. Tanner has pointed out, you can get away with only adjoining one root of $f$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.  From this, you'll find that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ is enough for $f$ to split.

Also, if you are having trouble finding the roots in $\mathbb{C}$, you may first try doing rational roots test.  This wont always work, but since $f$ is a degree $3$ polynomial, it will have a real root so that you at least have a chance.  In this case, you find that you do get a rational root, and now do long division to find the other factor of $f$.

Comment: I'm sorry, how is √-7 a root?

Comment: It's not.  But, if you adjoin $\sqrt{-7}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ then you can construct the roots.